# Mysql2::Error: Table 'conversations' already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, migration

I'm getting this error after trying to update a gem (mailboxer) and removing it.

Mysql2::Error: Table 'conversations' already exists: CREATE TABLE `conversations` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL)

I tried:

1. Bundle exec rake db:migrate rollback then rake db:migrate
2. Bundle exec rake db:migrate v= xxxxxxxx then rake db:migrate
3. getting rid of the migration files (that worked but I don't like the though of just getting rid of code)

I do not want to loose my data and drop the tables.
Any thoughts?

Update:

```
Rake db:migrate:status

   up     20140526010413  Adduserfollowme to users
   up     20140703193119  Add vote weight to votes
   up     20140713211140  Add partime to user
   up     20140716024440  Add devise to admin users
   up     20140716024510  Create active admin comments
   up     20140727042518  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20140727051902  Add slug to activities
  down    20140728031732  Create mailboxer.mailboxer engine
  down    20140728031733  Add notified object.mailboxer engine
  down    20140728031734  Add notification code.mailboxer engine
  down    20140728031735  Add attachments.mailboxer engine
  down    20140728031736  Rename receipts read.mailboxer engine
  down    20140728031737  Add global notification support.mailboxer engine

rake db:rollback

==  AddSlugToActivities: reverting ============================================
-- remove_index("activities", {:column=>:slug})
   -> 0.0215s
-- remove_column("activities", :slug)
   -> 0.0342s
==  AddSlugToActivities: reverted (0.0559s) ===================================

Rake db:migrate

==  AddSlugToActivities: migrating ============================================
-- add_column(:activities, :slug, :string)
   -> 0.0266s
-- add_index(:activities, :slug)
   -> 0.0104s
==  AddSlugToActivities: migrated (0.0373s) ===================================

==  CreateMailboxer: migrating ================================================
-- create_table(:conversations)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'conversations' already exists: CREATE TABLE `conversations` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `query'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `block in execute'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `execute'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:211:in `execute'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:170:in `create_table'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/foreigner-1.6.1/lib/foreigner/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:14:in `create_table'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:432:in `create_table'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in `method_missing'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/releases/20140728100705/db/migrate/20140728031732_create_mailboxer.mailboxer_engine.rb:6:in `up'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `up'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `call'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/home/bill/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:179:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

What should I do next?

Comment: Have you updated from 0.11.0 (or minor) to 0.12.0?

Comment: Warantesbr...yes I did but I had to remove the 0.12.0 and reinstall the 0.11.0 since I kept having errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `rake db:migrate rollback`, only `rake db:rollback`
Try `rake db:migrate:status`, then use `rake db:rollback` to make unwanted migrations to be down.

Sometimes when 'something went wrong' and you migrate-rollback a lot, it is necessary to comment up some lines, make migrate\rollback and incomment them again.

If it doesnt work, try show code of migrations that fail

Comment: Ok... I just reread your answer. I commented  all the code that was up in the down migration. Then rake db:migrate again .. no errors. Then raked:migrate:status and everything was up on the first column. then everything was working as usual! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: No problem. But you should keep in mind that such steps (commenting, uncommenting) - mean that something went wrong: maybe you manually edited your database, or not properly specified UP and DOWN migration etc. In perfect world this shouldnt happen and you have to get enough of rollback\migrate