# Mysql2::Error: Table "Admin_Users" already exists

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

***--------------------------EDIT #1--------------------------***

***I found a way around my problem:***

**The Problem:**

I typo'd "admin_user", when it should have been "admin_users" in my migration, and ran rake db:migrate. Giving an ERROR before completing the migration.

**A Solution:**

```
rake db:drop #drops the database
rake db:create #re-creates the database
```

**A Question:**

How would I have fixed migrating a typo without dropping my whole database and re-creating it? Obviously I don't want to be deleting data with a real project.

**EDIT #2
Answer to my question^:**

You can go into your code and comment the code that has been already migrated, which will finish the rest of your migration when you run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

**END OF EDIT #2**

**--------------------------END OF EDIT #1--------------------------**

I'm coming across a noobie MySQL problem using Ruby On Rails 4.

```
class AlterUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def up
    rename_table("users", "admin_users")
    add_column("admin_users", "username", :string, :limit => 25, :after => "email")
    change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, :limit => 100)
    rename_column("admin_users", "password", "hashed_password")
    puts "*** Adding an index is next ***"
    add_index("admin_users", "username")
end

def down
    remove_index("admin_users", "username")
    rename_column("admin_users", "hashed_password", "password")
    change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, :default => "", :null => false)
    remove_column("admin_users", "username")
    rename_table("admin_users", "users")
end
end
```

Then I ran:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Which then migrated "Create Users", but gave me an ERROR when hitting the Alter Users Migration:

```
*** Adding an index is next ***
-- add_index("admin_user", "username")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
Mysql2::Error: Table 'simple_cms_development.admin_user' doesn't exist: CREATE  INDEX `index_admin_user_on_username`  ON `admin_user` (`username`)
```

I then tried:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

Which resulted in:

```
up     20150911203937  Do nothing yet
up     20150911204213  Create users
down    20150911212536  Alter users
```

So I figured if I just reverted back to all DOWN status by using:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

But then gave me another Error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown table 'users': DROP TABLE `users`
/db/migrate/20150911204213_create_users.rb:16:in `down'
```

Obviously this is just a practice Database and RoR Project in general, but how can I fix this Error and in the BEST possible way so I won't delete anything important (in future SQL projects).

I've read these threads before posting here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988889/mysql2error-table-conversations-already-exists
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876009/ruby-on-rails-mysql2error-table-pages-already-exists-create-table-pages
```

Thank you for any answers/advice!

Comment: Great, I went into my MySQL database and actually deleted the Table (thinking it would revert back to default) "admin_users". Which didn't change anything. The statues are the same, and errors..  -_-, help pls.

Comment: Is there a field called username in the users table that you copied? If so, it might be failing on the creation of an already existing column.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense, your error (and apparent `db:migrate` output) show a problem because there's no `"admin_user"` (singular) table, and yet your migration shows `add_index("admin_users"...` (plural). On top of that the error in the subject of your question is never mentioned in your post. Definitely seems like you've gotten yourself in a mess, my recommendation is to drop the database and start from scratch.

Comment: I figured out I made a typo "admin_user", and then changed it to "admin_users".. AFTER rake db:migrate, though. I just dropped the whole database. Is there a way to "re-plug" the database back in?